# C++ iterative vs recursion optimizations in the compiler

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

Let's say I have a recursive function that calls itself many times (like a factorial) before it ever reaches the base case/gets a value to start unrolling the rest up the chain. Will the compiler optimize this to the same code as if i were to write that function in iterative format?

Comment: Depends on the compiler and (often) the precise details of how you write the code. gcc (for example) *can* do tail-call optimization, but doesn't always, even in some cases that it looks like it probably could.

Comment: In general is it better to write everything iterative instead of recursive?

Comment: Here is a good [article](http://32leav.es/?p=674) on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this is "maybe". But if you really want to MAKE SURE the compiler doesn't make the function actually recursive, then you have to write it iteratively.

Many compilers can detect "tail-recursion" and convert it to a loop. But not always, and not always with the same efficiency as if you wrote it yourself as an iterative function.

For more complex cases, such as Fibonacci series (which is not a simple tail recursive function), it's often hard for the compiler to actually realize what is going on, and it has to resort to actually making it recursive, even tho' it is quite trivial to make it iterative. [When I tried fibonacci in recursive method, my results were MUCH worse than the iterative method - indicating that the compiler didn't solve it - and that's using `gcc` which is usually fairly clever on these things].

Comment: Fibonacci is tricky, because there are two recursive calls.  And of course, only one can be a tail recursion (not that the compiler will always recognize it).

Comment: normally if you do fib(n-1)+fib(n-2) or whatever you have to also memoize the results correct?

Comment: A really good compiler would recognize the Fibonacci sequence and emit machine code for the lg N iterative algorithm, just to confuse novice programmers ;)

Comment: Yes, that was my point. I have added a bracket to explain that fibonaccis isn't tail recursive, and thus won't be so easily translated.

Comment: So is it considered bad practice to use recursion if this sort of risk is possible?

Comment: There are two problems with recursive functions: 1) Potential for stack overflows, where the number of recursive calls are not bounded to a low number, 2) inefficiency, where the recursive code is not as efficient as the iterative method (fibonacci is a good example here, as it is O(N<sup>2</sup>), with the iterative version being O(N) - for large N, that makes a big difference)

Comment: so basically "yes if N is large, probably not a big deal otherwise" ?

Comment: Yes, that sort of thing. There are also a lot of problems where recursive calls are very handy. Quicksort, binary tree search, etc. And the number of calls is naturally fairly limited (no more than log2(N) or some such), so you don't have to worry about overflowing the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, but be aware that the semantics of C++ often make it more difficult.  Those destructors which are called when you return mean that a lot that looks like tail recursion isn't.